# What does it mean "You don't need to be empathic"?

Tags: idioms, phrases

I want to know the meaning of this sentence or Idiom :

`You don't need to be empathic!`

Comment: What exactly about it don't you understand?  Do you understand the meaning of each individual word?

Comment: I want to know the whole sentence meaning, not each word. If it is not idiom, I want to know especially "empathic" meaning in this sentence.

Comment: It is not an idiom.  An idiom is a well-known phrase that has a meaning that is not the obvious, literal one.  This isn't a well-known phrase, and I don't see any meaning besides the obvious one: You do not have to have the quality of "empathy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sentence is a misquote of an idiom. The correct idioms are:

> I **don't need to be a mind-reader** to know that you fancy him
>
> I **don't need to be telepathic** to know that you fancy him

What this means is that it's obvious from my friend's behaviour what's going on inside her head. In this case the she is maybe staring at the boy all the time, isn't concentrating on what she is doing, and maybe wearing a silly grin when the boy walks by.

[empathic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/empathic) means that you understand and **sympathise with** somebody's feelings, thoughts and emotions.

[telepathic](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/telepathy) means that you know what is in somebody else's mind.

The important difference is that I know **what** my friend is thinking, but I don't necessarily **agree with it**.